# Calling a Base class method from Child class c++

Tags: c++, inheritance

i have 4 classes Product and MultiBuyProduct (which is a child of product) which are used to work out price, and a shopping cart which you can add to which calls functions from MultiBuyProduct gets their price and prints a receipt to console, and Amount which is a class that takes 2 ints and does some calculations on them eg add subtract and then returns a formatted price. from my main.cpp i call

```
 MultiBuyProduct p2("Wine", Amount(10,0), 2, 10);
 ShoppingCart SC;
 SC.add(&p2 ,2, true);
```

below shows shopping cart add method

```
void ShoppingCart::add(Product *p, int quantity, bool end)
{
    mProduct = p;
    //Sets member vairable value
    mQuantity = quantity;
    //Gets Name of product 'p'
    mProductName = mProduct->getName();
    //Gets price of product 'p'
    mAmount = mProduct->getPrice();
    //Gets total price of product 'p' based on quantity
    mAmountTotal = mProduct->getPrice(quantity);
    //Updates the GrandTotal
    mGrandTotal.add(mProduct->getPrice(0));
}
```

below shows MultiBuyProduct getPrice

```
Amount MultiBuyProduct::getPrice(int quantity)
{
    if(quantity >= mMinDiscountedQuantity)
    {
        mPrice.setFullPence(mPrice.getFullPence() * quantity);
        mPrice.setPounds(mPrice.getFullPence()/100);
        mPrice.setPence(mPrice.getFullPence()%100);

        int j = mPrice.getFullPence() / 100 * mDiscountedPercent;
        saving += j;
        int i = mPrice.getFullPence() - j;

        mPrice.setFullPence(i);
        mPrice.setPounds(i/100);
        mPrice.setPence(i%100);
        return Amount(mPrice.getFullPence()/100, mPrice.getFullPence()%100);
    }
    else
    {
        return Product::getPrice(quantity);
    }
}
```

ok so basically the functionality is working in that the correct total is printed to console showing that 10% has been discounted because quantity is more than or equal to 2.

but my else statement is reached (in shopping cart add method when looking for singular price of an item )

```
    mAmount = mProduct->getPrice();
```

but nothing is returned i think its because product for some reason contains no data that MultiBuyProduct has, i basically need to make Product have the same data as multiBuy product and then call the get price on it. (basically like in java i would call(else super.getPrice(quantity) <<< but i know you cant do that in c++)

EDIT: here is class structure for

Product:

```
Product::Product(std::string name, Amount price):aName(name), mPrice(price)
{
}
```

MultiBuyProduct:

```
MultiBuyProduct::MultiBuyProduct(std::string aName, Amount price, int minDiscountedQuantity, int discountedPercent)
    : mMinDiscountedQuantity(minDiscountedQuantity), mDiscountedPercent(discountedPercent),
      mPrice(price), aName(aName)
{
      mProduct = Product(mName,mPrice);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code works in Visual Studio 2008

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>

using namespace std;
class Product
{
protected:
    std::string aName;
    double mPrice;
public:
Product::Product(std::string name, double price):aName(name), mPrice(price)
{
}

double getPrice(int quantity)
{
    return mPrice*quantity;
}
};

class MultiBuyProduct : Product
{
    int mMinDiscountedQuantity, mDiscountedPercent;

public:
MultiBuyProduct::MultiBuyProduct(std::string name, double price, int minDiscountedQuantity, int discountedPercent)
    : mMinDiscountedQuantity(minDiscountedQuantity), mDiscountedPercent(discountedPercent), Product(name, price)
{
}
double MultiBuyProduct::getPrice(int quantity=1)
{
    if(quantity >= mMinDiscountedQuantity)
    {
        return (mPrice*quantity) - (mPrice*mDiscountedPercent/100);
    }
    else
    {
        return Product::getPrice(quantity);
    }
}
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    MultiBuyProduct p2("Wine", 10.0, 2, 10);
    MultiBuyProduct *mProduct = &p2;
    //Sets member vairable value
    int mQuantity = 2;
    //Gets Name of product 'p'
    //Gets price of product 'p'
    double price = mProduct->getPrice();
    //Gets total price of product 'p' based on quantity
    double mAmountTotal = mProduct->getPrice(mQuantity);
    //Updates the GrandTotal
    double mGrandTotal = mProduct->getPrice(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yea i thought that was the obvious answer too but when you do this is crashes on compile becasue aName and mPrice may not have been initialized yet

Comment: Can you try the edit please and get back on whether it worked?

Comment: ok so that will obviously work becasue the only thing thats changed is that price and name are now initialized in constructor but product isnt even initialized now?

Comment: if you look at my edit for multiBuyProduct constructor, i thought that would work and then call `mProduct.getPrice();` but it still doesnt theres no errors but it just doesnt have any values in it

Comment: MultiBuyProduct is derived from Product, right? If so Product will be initialised during the initialisation of MultiBuyProduct. You don't have to explicitly call the constructor of Product. But MultiBuyProduct is derived from Product, right? That's what I understood from your question.

Comment: Ok, so MultiBuyProduct is not derived from product? You have a variable named mProduct, in MultiBuy? Then check my edited answer. It should work.

Comment: multiBuyProduct is derived from Product yes but it would seem that product just has no values in it at all when it gets to the else statement it should be running a method in product which im sure it is but theres just no values in it so its returning 0

Comment: and my code is now as follows constructor has this in it `mProduct = Product(mName,mPrice);` and my return is `return mProduct.getPrice(quantity);` and still nothing comes back

Comment: i really dont understand why `return Product::getPrice(quantity);` doesnt just work if it is a derrived class

Comment: right the problem is that multi is derrived from product ok? so i have no idea what to put in my constructor or the return to just make it so that when `product.getPrice(quantity)` is called it actually has values

Comment: Could you change mProduct = Product(mName,mPrice); to mProduct = Product(name,price); don't use the member variables, instead use the parameters of the constructor itself.

Comment: yea it makes no difference when using mName and mPrice they are both initialized anyway i have changed it but still no different becasue by the time i call the method getPrice product seems to have no values in it even though iv initialized them in constructor

Comment: Hi, I tried a sample code on VS 2010 and came up with a bit of code. And I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks @premsuraj that really helped iv made some changes and got it working now